# Get actual value of a variable in another variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

For example, in below code, I want to set `@XYZ` with value of `@ABC` and value of `@DEF` i.e. `@XYZ` should be `PQRSTU`.

```
DECLARE @ABC VARCHAR(MAX)='PQR',
@DEF VARCHAR(MAX)='STU',
@XYZ VARCHAR(MAX);
```

Comment: do you mean setting the cells with value @XYZ to @ABC+@DEF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant concatenation, you can use

```sql
DECLARE @ABC VARCHAR(MAX)='PQR',
@DEF VARCHAR(MAX)='STU',
@XYZ VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @XYZ = CONCAT(@ABC,@DEF) 
--or 
SET @XYZ = @ABC + @DEF
```

```
+--------+
| PQRSTU |
+--------+
```

The advantage of [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is, if the value of the variable is null also, it will return empty string of `VARCHAR(1)` for that. So, your concatenation will be successful

```sql
SET @DEF = NULL

SET @XYZ = CONCAT(@ABC,@DEF)
SELECT @XYZ
```

```
+--------+
| PQR    |
+--------+
```

If you want to set value for a variable, you can do two ways:

```sql
SET  @xyz = value -- ANSI standard. works across RDBMS systems
SELECT @XYZ = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `select` or `set` keyword:

```
-- both are equivalent
SELECT @XYZ = @ABC + @DEF;
SET @XYZ = @ABC + @DEF;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
Can you also reply on below:
In a procedure, we are passing multiple input parameters. I want to store the values that were passed to the procedure.

Ex:

EXEC SP2 @BKP_TBL='TEMP_TABLE', @Filter='AA'.... and so on;

Procedure is:

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP2](
BKP_TBL VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL, --For some reason not able to add 'AT THE RATE' symbol
Filter VARCHAR(100)=NULL,
.
.
)
AS 
BEGIN
.
.
SELECT NAME from sys.parameters where object_id = @@PROCID; -- to get total all the input parameter names
.
.
END

Comment: @MahendraDhaker You shoudld ask another question, because it doesn't fit in comments. Also, take a look at stored procedures documentation (just google it). I am sure that docs will answer all your questions.